# A domain object created in a controller test does not end up in the database

Tags: grails, controller, mocking

I have been trying to follow the Grails in Action (GiA MEAP, 2nd edition), but every now and then I stumble on some issues that I cannot seem to figure out even after spending a lots of time. This is one of those. Sorry, this question is related to the example in the GiA (v13, ch6, PostControllerSpec in Listing 6.x, Pg. 144), but I will try to capture the issue with a stripped down but complete code. I have two domain models, `User` and `Post`.

```
package grailstuts

class User {
    String loginId
    static hasMany = [ posts: Post ]

    static constraints = { loginId(blank: false, unique: true) }
}
```

---

```
package grailstuts

class Post {
    String content
    static belongsTo = [ user: User]

    static constraints = { content(blank: false) }
}
```

The `PostController` is as follows.

```
package grailstuts

class PostController {
    static scaffold = true

    def timeline() {
        def user = User.findByLoginId(params.id)
        if (!user) {
            response.sendError(404)
        } else {
            [ user : user ]
        }
    }

    def addPost() {
        def user = User.findByLoginId(params.id)
        if (user) {
            def post = new Post(params)
            user.addToPosts(post)
            if (user.save()) {
                flash.message = "Successfully created Post"
            } else {
                flash.message = "Invalid or empty post"
            }
        } else {
            flash.message = "Invalid User Id"
        }
        redirect(action: 'timeline', id: params.id)
    }
}
```

When I try unit testing the controller as follows (as given in the book), I have the issue.

```
package grailstuts

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(PostController)
@Mock([User,Post])
class PostControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def "Adding a valid new post to the timeline"() {
        given: "A user with posts in the db"
        User chuck = new User(loginId: "chuck_norris").save(failOnError: true)

        and: "A loginId parameter"
        params.id = chuck.loginId

        and: "Some content for the post"
        params.content = "Chuck Norris can unit test entire applications with a single assert."

        when: "addPost is invoked"
        def model = controller.addPost()

        then: "our flash message and redirect confirms the success"
        flash.message == "Successfully created Post"
        response.redirectedUrl == "/post/timeline/${chuck.loginId}"
        Post.countByUser(chuck) == 1
    }
}
```

The test passes the first two tests `flash.message == "Successfully created Post"` and `response.redirectedUrl == "/post/timeline/${chuck.loginId}"`, but fails at the last line `Post.countByUser(chuck) == 1` (which is very puzzling and cannot figure out why that fails). I get the following:

```
|  Condition not satisfied:
Post.countByUser(chuck) == 1
     |           |      |
     0           |      false
                 grailstuts.User : 1
```

My question is why does the above test fail, even though it successfully created the post? I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out the bug, but no luck yet.

Comment: Have you also tried flushing during saving user in controller? `user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`? Also see if it fails while save with `failOnError`.

Comment: Thank you, @dmahapatro. In fact yes, I had tried that too. Meaning, if I replace `if (user.save())` with `if (user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true))` in the `addPost()`, it does *NOT* fail. Instead, the first two tests still pass and it fails only at the third line `Post.countByUser(chuck) == 1` (exactly as in my original question). However, if I `println post.id` after the save, it gives `null` (that is a hint but I still do not understand how it can save the user without fail, but I cannot find the post in the database).

Comment: Are you sure that the `loginId` is `unique`?

Comment: I think so, as I have specified the constraint `loginId(blank: false, unique: true)`, and there is no other user in the database yet. However, I may be missing something (I am a newbie to Grails), so if you could kindly elaborate on what exactly you mean, I can give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: I was aiming at the same. Can you just `assert Post.all` above failing assertion?

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro. Just tried that, and the `assert Post.all` fails (but `assert Post.all == []` passes). So there are no posts saved in the database. But I am puzzled why the post was not saved in the database in the first place (I think the post should have been saved).

Comment: May be because of the `id` you have in the `params` in the test. Just save Post with the content directly as `new Post(content: params.content)`. And if possible change `params.id` to `params.loginId`, the former is misleading and would not play fair.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43543/discussion-between-tikka-and-dmahapatro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After countless tries, I did something that worked. However, I am still very puzzled, and if someone can explain it that would really help. The only change I made for it to work was saved the `post` *explicitly* if `user.save()` was `true`. Here is the modified `addPost()` (the only line changed is marked clearly with `// save the post explicitly!!`, and there is no other change anywhere else).

```
def addPost() {
    def user = User.findByLoginId(params.id)
    if (user) {
        def post = new Post(params)
        user.addToPosts(post)
        if (user.save()) {
            post.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)       // save the post explicitly!!
            flash.message = "Successfully created Post"
        } else {
            flash.message = "Invalid or empty post"
        }
    } else {
        flash.message = "Invalid User Id"
    }
    redirect(action: 'timeline', id: params.id)
}
```

One note: Even if I did `if (user.save(flush: true))` instead of just `if (user.save())` but did not include the explicit save for the post as `post.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`, it did not work. I *had* to save the post explicitly.

Since saving the `user` should have saved the `post` automatically, this behavior still puzzles me. If someone can explain this behavior it would be very helpful. Thanks to those who took the time to look into this.

**UPDATE --**
**Explanation from Peter Ledbrook  below ([link here](https://github.com/GrailsInAction/graina2/issues/64)):**

> Which version of Grails are you using? I just tried with Grails 2.2.1
>   and got a NullPointerException in that test. Upgrading to 2.2.4 fixed
>   that particular problem. Could be a Grails issue.
>
> FYI, you shouldn't even need to explicitly save the User instance in
>   the action to persist the Post. So something is definitely wrong. The
>   cascading save is broken, probably in Grails' mock database
>   implementation that's used during unit tests. I'm guessing that the
>   application works fine when run normally (via run-app for example).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I think the problem is with

```
 def post = new Post(params)
```

As it was adding

```
params.id: "chuck_norris"
```

to the Post creation, but strangely not params.content.

I solved mine by changing the line to

```
def post = new Post(content: params.content)
```